# Any gotchas when upgrading Unity v2.1 to v3.0?

Tags: asp.net, unity-container, enterprise-library, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a legacy ASP.NET WebForms 3.5 application suite which extensively uses EnterpriseLibrary v5; big chunks of the core libraries are also used in console apps and Windows services. We use Unity v2.1 (a dependency of EntLib5) throughout.

For a new project, which uses ASP.NET MVC 5, someone has suggested that we use Unity v3, outwardly a good suggestion, especially as the Unity.MVC5 library does not support Unity v2. If we upgraded to v3, are we likely to have trouble along the way, especially with EntLib (I *really* doubt that we would get sign off if we have to upgrade EntLib to a newer version, due to the amount of extra testing that would be required)?

Comment: I think it is a good practices to start a new project with the latest version of a library. If you don't have specific constrains against each particular lib. btw I was told that Unity v4 will bring performance boost but also some backward incompatibility (read - interceptions).

Comment: I think EntLib could end up being a big constraint :-)

Comment: Do you really want/need to use EntLib in the new project? I think each block has a better replacement now days.

Comment: Oh absolutely, but the new code will still have dependencies on existing libraries, which have dependencies on EntLib. Personally I would rather have it taken outside and terminated with extreme prejudice, but such is life in anything other than the greenest of greenfield development...